# 24 hour date time graph plotted on x axis in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, graph

So im trying to plot a graph with the date on the x axis and the tide in metres on the y axis over a 2 week period, like this:

[image]

with this information:

[image]

If tried using scatter graphs but I don't know how to add the date aspect of the chart.

If you could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have data without LW, HW values and repeat the date for the time values and choose **Line chart** as the chart type. You will get data as in the image.

```
Date     |    Time    |     Height
---------------------------------------
9/28/2015|  3:54:00 AM|     4.65
---------------------------------------
9/28/2015|  10:02:00 AM|    1.68
---------------------------------------
9/28/2015|  4:11:00 PM |    4.89
---------------------------------------
9/28/2015|  10:28:00 PM|    1.40
----------------------------------------
9/29/2015|  3:54:00 AM |    4.88
----------------------------------------
9/30/2015| 10:02:00 AM |    1.38
----------------------------------------
10/1/2015| 4:11:00 PM  |    5.10
-----------------------------------------
```

[image: Line Chart for tide]

**EDIT**

Insert new column called *RoundedTime*; You can round-off the Time to nearest 12 Hour using `=MROUND(D2,"12:00")` formula; and then create Line chart using *Date, RoundedTime, Height* fields.

Click *Line* in the chart and choose Format button in the chart as *highlighted* and in the bottom, choose *smooth line*. Now, you will get smooth line chart as given in the below image.

[image: Smooth Line Chart]

Comment: Hmm i didnt realise, thanks. is there no possible way to may the X axis time in increments of 00:00, 12:00, 00:00 12:00 and such?? and the only reason why i had the scatter graph option was so that i could have that curved line aesthetic. is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine if you put the date and time together to make a date time type. You do this just by creating another column, adding the first two columns and formatting the third column as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (in my locale).

Then choose scatter with smoothing as the chart type.

I had to rotate the axis labels to fit them in and fix the min to the first date serial number (42275) and the max to the date two days later (42277) (because I couldn't be  bothered to type in all the data), then fix the major tick marks to .25 (or .5) of a day.

[image]

Comment: Ah perfect thank so much!! iv managed to do it. The other thing I was wondering is how to make the graph line start on the Y axis margin? and how to get rid of the couple of days before and after the the graph finishes?

Comment: I think you can do both just by fixing the maximum and minimum of the graph. However, if you don't have any data before 03:54 on 28th September, may have to add an extra point at the beginning - either use 21:43 on 27th, or estimate the level at midnight( I make it about 2.7m). Unfortunately if you try and make the minimum 03:54, that will shift all your tick marks.

Comment: BTW I can't test this because I've got it set up on my home computer and I'm at work - it's only lunch time here.